# Mostrar registros en dos columnas en php mysql bootstrap (movil)

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap

Sucede que estoy intentado mostrar unos registros en un móvil los cuales con `Bootstrap` se muestran en una columna, pero lo que quiero es que se muestre en dos columnas, he intentado de todo pero `Bootstrap` en  móvil siempre lo muestra en una columna.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código el cual muestra los registros:

```
<?php
$sql1= "select *  from imagenes";
$query = $con->query($sql1);
?>

<?php if($query->num_rows>0):?>
<?php while ($imagen=$query->fetch_array()):?>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body p-t-10">
                    <div class="media-main">
                              <img src="<?php echo $imagen['img'] ?>" width="100" height="100" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro, es que estás haciendo dos cosas. La primera le estas agregando una etiqueta `hr` que hace un salto de línea por defecto y la segunda le estás indicando que en pantallas pequeñas use las 12 columnas del `grid`... `<div class="col-sm-12">`.

Para solucionar lo primero, debes mover el `<hr>` dentro del `div` y no fuera de el.

Para solucionar la segunda, basta con usar `<div class="col-6">` sin establecer el tamaño de la pantalla... Algo así.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body p-t-10">
          <div class="media-main">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body p-t-10">
          <div class="media-main">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Si necesitas que en pantallas más grandes se muestren mas imágenes en cada `row` debes establecer la cantidad de columnas que ocupara cada `div`. Por ejemplo `<div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3">`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body p-t-10">
          <div class="media-main">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body p-t-10">
          <div class="media-main">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body p-t-10">
          <div class="media-main">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body p-t-10">
          <div class="media-main">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body p-t-10">
          <div class="media-main">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Es importante tener en cuenta el tamaño de las imágenes para que no desborden el tamaño del `container` y otras cosas a tener en cuenta, pero básicamente es eso que te menciono.

Ejecuta los snippet en pantalla completa para que puedas notar la diferencia.

Comment: Aunque, pensándolo bien, la etiqueta `<hr>` donde la tienes no debería afectar. Intenta primero lo del `grid` sin mover el `<hr>`.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación, funciono